# python regular expression numbers in a row

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to check a string for a maximum of 3 numbers in a row for which I used:

```
regex = re.compile("\d{0,3}")
```

but this does not work for instance the string `1234` would be accepted by this regex even though the digit string if over length 3.

Comment: What doesn't work? What is your input, what output did you get?

Comment: I tried helping you by answering your question, I have since deleted my answer and all comments. The reason for this is that your question was very unclear, there are many things wrong with what you posted, and by answering them, and providing a DIRECT solution to your answer, I was shocked at how you told me it was WRONG. You were right, it was wrong for me to answer the question you posted, instead of the problem that you have with your code that you did not post. In the future I recommend you provide more information so it can reduce frustration of those trying to help you.

Comment: @InbarRose if the question was so unclear to you then you should not have answered and ever worse you posted comments on others answers stating they're wrong (when they are indeed correct) and now you 'shocked' that the OP told you that your incorrect answers wasn't what he was looking for!?!?

Comment: I do not want to draw out a discussion, let alone an argument. The original question was about getting a regular expression to match numbers of up to 3 digits. The fact that the OP wanted to use this information to later find strings that did or did not have numbers of up to this many digits, was not part of the original question. My answer explained where the errors in the actual expression itself were, and also showed an example of finding 1, 2, or 3 digit numbers. Suddenly the question is about matching strings that don't have any numbers over 3 digits in them... what would you say to that?

Comment: @InbarRose this was and still is the original question: `I'm trying to check a string for a maximum of 3 numbers in a row` you are complaining about behavior which you yourself was acting, you tried to help but in this case you was wrong, be more gracious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check a string for a maximum of 3 digits in string you need to use `'\d{4,}'` as you are only interest in the digits string over a length of 3.

```
import re

str='123abc1234def12'
print re.findall('\d{4,}',str)

>>> '[1234]'
```

If you use `{0,3}`:

```
str='123456'
print re.findall('\d{0,3}',str)

>>> ['123', '456', '']
```

The `regex` matches digit strings of maximum length 3 and empty strings but this cannot  be used to test correctness. Here you can't check whether all digit strings are in length but you can easily check for digits string over the length.

So to test do something like this:

```
str='1234'

if re.match('\d{4,}',str):
    print 'Max digit string too long!'

>>> Max digit string too long!
```

Comment: Why 4? I would expect `{1,3}` to meet the requirement; four are definitely more than "a maximum of three".

Comment: @tripleee exactly the `OP` is trying to validate strings to only allow a maximum of 3 in a row so you need to check for `4+` to find if the string is correct.

Comment: actually I won't to check the string for 4+ numbers in a row so if the string contains 0, 1, 2 or 3 numbers in a row its fine but when it contains 4+ numbers then not fine

Comment: @user1606657 great, thanks for clarifying. Just use `if re.match('\d{4,}',str):` to test for digit strings longer than 3. Please accept and upvote this answer if you found it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

`\d{0}` matches every possible string. It's not clear what you mean by "doesn't work", but if you expect to match a string with digits, increase the repetition operator to `{1,3}`.

If you wish to exclude runs of 4 or more, try something like `(?:^|\D)\d{1,3}(?:\D|$)` and of course, if you want to capture the match, use capturing parentheses around `\d{1,3}`.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a couple reasons:

- Since you want `\d` to search for digits or numbers, you should probably spell that as `"\\d"` or `r"\d"`. `"\d"` might happen to work, but only because `d` isn't special (yet) in a string. `"\n"` or `"\f"` or `"\r"` will do something totally different. Check out the [re module documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) and search for "raw strings".
- `"\\d{0,3}"` will match just about anything, because {0,3} means "zero or up to three". So, it will match the start of any string, since any string starts with the empty string.
- or, perhaps you want to be searching for strings that are only zero to three numbers, and nothing else. In this case, you want to use something like `r"^\d{0,3}$"`. The reason is that regular expressions match anywhere in a string (or only at the beginning if you are using `re.match` and not `re.search`). `^` matches the start of the string, and `$` matches the end, so by putting those at each end you are not matching anything that has anything before or after `\d{0,3}`.

Answer (score 0):

The method you have used is to find substrings with 0-3 numbers, it couldn't reach your expactation.
My solve:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall('\d','ds1hg2jh4jh5')
['1', '2', '4', '5']
>>> res = re.findall('\d','ds1hg2jh4jh5')
>>> len(res)
4
>>> res = re.findall('\d','23425')
>>> len(res)
5
```

so,next you just need use ‘if’ to judge the numbers of digits.